# How to determine the height that i need to set for UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How can i set the height of the UICollectionView programmatically depending on how much cells are in it?

So far this is what i thought of,

```
    CGFloat cellHeight = 100;
    CGFloat height = [imageFilesArray count] * cellHeight;
    CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 177, width, height);
```

Also when i do this, the bottom half of the collection view is not responding to didSelect

Comment: Could please tell me, is your collection view added from storyboard/xib and are you using auto layouts?

Comment: @BharatModi i created my collectionView programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the height of the collection view based on the number of items to be displayed. Here is a small function to calculate height of the collection view.

This method displays two elements in a row. You can modify according to your needs.

```
func calculateCollectionViewHeight(imageList:[AnyObject]) -> CGFloat {
    if imageList.count <= 2 {
      return 320 // if will set height to 320 if there is only two or less than 2 element in the list
    }
    if products.count % 2 == 0 {
      return CGFloat(295 * (products.count / 2)) // this will calculate the height of collection view if list is even 
    }else{
      return CGFloat(295 * (products.count / 2 + 1)) // this will calculate the height of collection view if list is odd 
    }

  }
```

now just call

```
collectionView.frame.size.height = calculateCollectionViewHeight(tempArray) // list of objects
```

Comment: Where should i set the height in my code? WillDisplayCell?

Comment: You can set the height in viewDidLoad or before reloading collectionView , after getting your list

Comment: how would i do it if i have 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

```
 static int  columns = 4;

int yushu = self.dataSource.count%columns;
int shang = (int)self.dataSource.count/columns;
int lineNum = 0;
if (yushu == 0) {
    lineNum = shang;
}else
{
    lineNum = shang +1 ;
}
height = cellHeight*lineNum
```

My English is poor，I hope this  can solve your problem。

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help you (I'm not sure as you are doing this programatically)

```
//Get the height required for collectionView content
CGFloat height = collectionView.contentSize.height;

CGRect collectionViewFrame = collectionView.frame;

//Update collectionView height
collectionViewFrame.size.height = height;
```

Or instead i would prefer using auto layouts, you can set constraints programatically also if you wish to using VFL. The above solution definitely work in auto layouts.